# Is there a standards organization or methodology to determine the elastic material properties of common materials?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, elastic-modulus

Is there a standards organization or methodology to determine the elastic material properties of common materials?  What constants are normally used to define these properties?

More specifically, the set of equations for linear elasticity can be written as:

$$
\nabla\cdot\sigma + {F} = \rho\ddot{{u}}\\
{\varepsilon} =\tfrac{1}{2} \left[{\nabla}{u}+({\nabla}{u})^\mathrm{T}\right]\\
{\sigma} = {C}:{\varepsilon}
$$

where

- $\sigma$ - Stress tensor
- $\epsilon$ - Strain tensor
- $u$ - Displacement
- $C$ - Stiffness tensor

Using Voigt notation, we can write the stiffness tensor as a $6\times 6$ symmetric matrix

$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13} & C_{14} & C_{15} & C_{16}\\
 & C_{22} & C_{23} & C_{24} & C_{25} & C_{26}\\
 & & C_{33} & C_{34} & C_{35} & C_{36}\\
 & & & C_{44} & C_{45} & C_{46}\\
 & & & & C_{55} & C_{56}\\
 & & & & & C_{66}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To me, this matrix $C$ defines the elastic material properties of a material, but I've been unable to find any reference or database that lists materials in this format.  I've found a few random materials that list their properties in terms of something like the bulk and shear modulus, which then map to this tensor as:

$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda + 2\mu & \lambda & \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 & \lambda + 2\mu & \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 & & \lambda + 2\mu & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 & & & \mu & 0 & 0\\
 & & & & \mu & 0\\
 & & & & & \mu
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where

- $\lambda$ - First Lame parameter
- $\mu$ - Shear modulus
- $\lambda + 2\mu/3$ - Bulk modulus

However, this only works for isotropic materials.  Generally speaking, we need all 21 elements of $C$.  As such, I didn't know if there is a standards organization or methodology for determining these properties beyond the shear and bulk modulus.  Alternatively, if shear and bulk are the only parameters really needed, how are these determined and what organization standardizes these tests?